# Show iCal subscription as busy for other coworkers

Tags: calendar, outlook, icalendar

Is it possible to subscribe to an iCal feed in Outlook and overlay it in your own Outlook Calendar and show it as busy/out of office for other people when creating appointments?

The scenario is as follows: we have a scheduling program that makes work schedules for our employees. This program can output ical feeds so our employees can subscribe to those feeds on their mobile phones. At our office we work with Outlook and we would like that the iCal feed would also be displayed and updated dynamically on every employees calendar. For the employee this is visible but not for other people trying to create an appointment via Outlook.

Best regards,
Rémy

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to have two kinds of feeds:

- one normal one with all the details for the individuals feed, that perhaps
  only they know the url for, and
- another feed that issues VFREEBUSY components https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#page-60 instead of VEVENTS.  THE VFREEBUSY component then just has the FREEBUSY info

Comment: But who requests this VFreeBusy message? Can Outlook ask for such messages through an URL at a web server?

Comment: Hi - they are both just URL's / ics files that one can subscribe to.  I don't know much about outlook, but if it can subscribe to a ics file with VEVENTS, then it should be able to subscribe to an ics file that also have VFREEBUSY components.     How you offer/present those urls up for subscription to by the employees is not something I can comment on.